# Magento 1: Minimum Order Amount excluding shipping cost?

Tags: checkout

I have an issue with Minimum Order Amount in Magento 1. This value I set up in Backend is including shipping cost too. Minimum Ordered Amount is actually Total Amount, can I set up minimum order amount only for total of product costs?

Here is an example: Product price is 45 USD, Shipping cost 10 USD, Minimum Order Amount 100 USD. If you order 2 pieces your Total Amount will be 2 * 45 + 10 = 100 and Magento accepts it. I would like to change the minimum order amount to exclude those 10 USD shipping cost.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you setup Minimum Order Amount? If you setup in **Configuration-Sales-Minimum Order Amount**, no shipping cost calculate. See below picture:[image]

Comment: In the same place you mentioned in your post. Is there any other place for checking?

Comment: You also can set minimum order amount for each shipping method